# AWS SNS custom confirmation Subscription email

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

is it possible to change or use a template to customize the email send by AWS SNS on a topic subscription ?
minimally, changing the language english to french.

i watched all the options on the console of AWS Sns, SES, SDK too and found nothing about that.

Answer (score 4):

As per the AWS [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-email-notifications.html),

> You can't customize the body of the email message. The email delivery feature is intended to provide internal system alerts, not marketing messages.

To send customized or marketing messages, utilize the [lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-lambda-as-subscriber.html) function to subscribe to the SNS events, and then internally use [SES](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/send-personalized-email-api.html) templates.

Comment: Thanks, it was confirmed by our AWS support guy. No customizable template for SNS subscription